# Time delaying computer move tic tac toe

Tags: java, android

I am just learning Java/Android, and have wrote a simple tic tac toe program. Everything works, but the game play feels weird. I have 9 methods (1 for each move) If its a one player game playerTest will call a computerMove method. I would like to move, than have a 2 second delay than the computer moves. When I time delay the computer move. The program waits 2 seconds and displays my move, and the computers move at the same time.

```
 public void displayForPosition1(View view) {

        piecePlaced = false;
        // Determine the players piece

        if (pos1.equals("") && !gameOver) {

            if (sound) {
                Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.position2);
                final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Main2Activity.this, R.raw.button_sound);
                mp.start();
            }

            if (moveCounter % 2 == 0) {
                piece = player1;
            } else {
                piece = player2;
            }

            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.position1);
            scoreView.setText(piece);

            moveCounter++;
            pos1 = piece;
            winTest();
        }
        playerTest();
    }
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: No the time delay part is easy. I want the game to feel more realistic. So that when I move my piece is placed, than a short delay, than the computers piece is placed. Instead of appearing that my move and the computers move are placed at the same time. The method displayForPosition1 is called from the xml onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do this, but from what I can see of your code, I think this should work.

The on-screen view will not be updated with the player's move until the `displayForPosition1` method returns, and that method will not return until the `playerTest` method does too. Your 2 second delay is inside the `playerTest` method, and then the computer moves and it's move is also displayed. So, `displayForPosition1` will not return, and the new view will not appear on screen, until after the 2 second delay and the computer's move.

One solution might be to execute the `playerTest` method on a new `Thread`. Then the `displayForPosition1` method will return immediately, and the player's move will be displayed. Meanwhile, the second thread will sleep for 2 seconds and then make the computer's move.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        playerTest();
    }}).start();
```

My fear is that when `playerTest` is executed outside the `displayForPosition1` method, the computer's move will not be displayed until `displayForPosition1` is next executed. So both moves will still appear at the same time. But try it, and see what happens.

Comment: It was crashing, so i used a handler, and now it works great. Thanks.

final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            playerTest();
        }
    };   


myHandler.post(myRunnable);